# User has_many tests, tests has_many grades. how to get count of grades?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this count.
Models are User, Test, Grade

User has_many Tests,  Tests has_many Grades.

each grade has a calculated score (strong_pass, pass, fail, strong_fail).

how can I get a count of each grade category?

For clarity, a User might take a Math test 4 times until they pass it.  they might receive grades in the spectrum (pass, fail, etc..)

but I want to know, of all tests taken for user X, how many passes, how many fails?

`user.tests.grades.passed.count`  is what I hoped would work. but doesn't
(I do have named scopes for 'passed', 'failed', etc.. in Grade model)

```
Class Grade

  def self.passed
    where(:grade => "passed")
  end

  def self.failed
    where(:grade => "failed")
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `User.tests.passed.count`, or is it called on an instance of `User`?

Comment: Please post your code for the `passed` and `failed` scopes as well.

Comment: It is an instance of User, because I need these counts for each user.  So yes, I was planning on it being a User instance method.  the 'passed', 'failed' methods are class methods.  So, now i can run Test.passed.count and I get the count of all users.

Comment: passed and failed scopes added. (in truth they aren't scopes, but class methods)

Comment: oops. these methods are in the Grade model not the Test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests
  has_many :grades, through: :tests
end

user = User.first

user.grades.passed.count
user.grades.failed.count
```

Comment: I thought to do this you had to have a join table?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association.  Grade model doesn't know about the user, only the test.    will this still work?

Comment: Join tables are typically used for `has_and_belongs_to_many` type relationships, which can be used with `has_many ... :through` as well, but the example in the link you posted is identical to your situation.